# Collective Noun for Religious Implements

Tags: single-word-requests, religion

Is there a general term to describe the instruments used in Christian rituals like the mass? I am referring to cruets to hold the bread and wine, the paten, ciborium, chalice and the like.

Answer (score 1):

If you are discussing them (liturgy, aesthetics, history) then @fev gives three excellent terms.

If you are polishing them, arranging them or replenishing, then 'sacred vessels' is the usual term.

[Sacred vessels,Liturgical objects,Eucharistic objects](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Sacred%20Vessels%2C%20Mass%20objects%2C%20Liturgical%20Objects%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=0&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CSacred%20Vessels%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CLiturgical%20Objects%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CSacred%20Vessels%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CLiturgical%20Objects%3B%2Cc0) Google e-books  ngram viewer

Answer (score 0):

I think they enter in the category of ***Eucharistic objects*** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Eucharistic_objects))

They are also called ***[Liturgical objects](https://d2y1pz2y630308.cloudfront.net/15664/documents/2017/1/Church%20Liturgical%20Objects%20and%20Terms%20011717.pdf)***.

It seems that in the Catholic Church, ***sacramentals*** includes both *acts* and *objects*:

> Roman Catholic Church: ***an action***, as the sign of the cross, a ceremony resembling a sacrament, ***or a sacred object***, regarded as being instituted by the church rather than by Christ and serving as a means of receiving sanctifying grace.([dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sacramental))

So *sacramentals* includes the objects you are referring to, but is not restricted to it.

Comment: *Sacramentals* isn't right. The sacred vessels are not [sacramentals](https://www.catholic.com/encyclopedia/sacramentals). [More here](https://www.catholic.com/search?q=sacramentals).

Comment: Eucharistic means pertaining to the Eucharist - i.e. the Mass. The Mass is not the only Christian rite, so "Liturgical objects" would be better".